# Link to a specific domain to a specific port : Nginx, Docker, Google cloud Service

Tags: docker, nginx, dns, docker-compose, google-compute-engine

I am trying to link a domain I purchased to my Google Cloud service, using docker a Nginx but, I have try so many solution write on Stackoverflow... but all failed.

What did I miss... Do you have any idea ? 
There is my files

**Environnement**

```
Domain : Google domain

Server : Google Cloud Service / compute engine / Centos 7.0;

Container : Docker / Docker-compose / Nginx
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY ./client/dist ./
COPY ./docker/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**docker-compose**

```
app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=prod
      - PORT=8081
    volumes:
      - /usr/share/nginx/html
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
```

**Nginx**

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.net;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;
    charset utf-8;

    # enable gzip
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_min_length 1100;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types
        text/plain
        text/css
        text/js
        text/xml
        text/javascript
        application/javascript
        application/x-javascript
        application/json
        application/xml
        application/rss+xml
        image/svg+xml;

    location ~* ^.+\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ {
        expires      30d;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(css|js|txt|xml|swf|wav)$ {
        expires      24h;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(html|htm)$ {
        expires      1h;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(eot|ttf|otf|woff|svg)$ {
        expires max;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_read_timeout 1800;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1800;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}
```

**Google Cloud Firewall**

[Google Cloud Firewall Port Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYkIw.png)

I have a domain I have purchased (ex. example.net) and I have an VueJs app running on port 8081.
My application is working on example.net:8081... But I want it running only on example.net... But nothing...

Hope some will find where I am making a mistake...

**Thank you for reading**

PS : There is some people who will tell me this is probably a duplicate post but... 1. I do not find any good anwser to this, I would not ask for help I would find it. 2. Don't be mean please).

Comment: `8081:80` you current bind container port 80 to 8081 on your server machine. But you want access to your domain without port, right ? So, bind 80 port inside container to `80` port on serrver by change`8081:80` to `80:80` . And make sure theris nothing use 80 port on real serve machine by command `sudo lsof -i tcp:80`

Comment: Thanks you very much ! I will try this !!

Comment: @TruongDang Problem solved ! Thanks a lot!

Comment: So happy when i can help you ^^

Comment: @Truong Dang Please post it as an answer for community visibility

Comment: @Digil Okay.....^^

Comment: @JérômeDupuis Can I make this as an anwser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`8081:80` you current bind container port `80 to 8081` on your server machine. But you want access to your domain without port, right ? So, bind `80 port` inside container to `80 port` on serrver by change `8081:80` to `80:80` . 
And make sure theris nothing use `80 port` on real serve machine by command:

`sudo lsof -i tcp:80`